# Turning an array of a sorted dictionary back into a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, filter

I have a `[String : CustomUserInfo]` dictionary. The key is an unique ID and the value is a custom object that contains user infos like `displayName`. The custom object `CustomUserInfo` conforms to `Comparable` and `Hashable`.

I am searching for a string and want only three key value pairs returned.

First I'm filtering the dictionary by `displayName`. This gives me a new dictionary with all key value pairs that are equal or larger then the string I am searching for.

Second I am sorting the dictionary by `displayName`, which gives me an array. Each element containing a key value pair.

If I got more than three elements in the array I remove the rest. That leaves me with an array of three elements.

The problem is, how do I convert this array back to a dictionary?

Alternative: is there a way to change the code in the closure after `.filter` to only return the three most relevant results? Skipping the whole round trip to an array and back to a dictionary.

I do need that because part of my code requires to access the `CustomUserInfo` objects by its key.

Here is a simplified playground version of my code:

```
import UIKit

    //MARK: - Struct containing the static user dictionary.

    struct Users {
        static var users: [String : CustomUserInfo] = [

        "cjry" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Luke"),
        "sorg" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Leia"),
        "vhue" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Yoda"),
        "sjdy" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Vader"),
        "vgdr" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Chewbacca"),
        "awdr" : CustomUserInfo(displayName: "Han")
    ]
}

//MARK: - CustomUserInfo object

struct CustomUserInfo {
    var displayName: String
}

extension CustomUserInfo: Comparable, Hashable {
    static func < (lhs: CustomUserInfo, rhs: CustomUserInfo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.displayName.lowercased() < rhs.displayName.lowercased()
    }
}

//MARK: - The search by string method.

func searchUsers(by searchString: String) {

    let searchString = searchString.lowercased()

    let filteredUsers = Users.users.filter { $0.1.displayName.lowercased() >= searchString }
    var sortedUsers = filteredUsers.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1  }
    if sortedUsers.count > 3 {
        sortedUsers.removeLast(sortedUsers.count - 3)
    }

    //sortedUsers is of type [Dictionary<String, CustomUserInfo>.Element] but needs to be [String : CustomUserInfo]
    print(sortedUsers)

}

searchUsers(by: "Ha")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to convert it back to dictionary, with some other changes I would write the function as

```
func searchUsers(by searchString: String) {
    let searchString = searchString.lowercased()

    let result = Users.users.filter { $0.1.displayName.lowercased() >= searchString }
        .sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
        .prefix(3)
        .reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }

    print(result)
}
```

Comment: This is very short and elegant! Works as it should. Another solution was using `let dictOfUsers = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sortedUsers.lazy.map { ($0.key, $0.value) })` but this is a bit longer.